# why is the fontawesome icon not showing in my web page?

Tags: html, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I have a basic html page like this, but the `fa-copy` icon doesn't show. why is that? I've tried consulting with chatgpt but all it's answers doesn't work. any help is appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-wzi+VRa3kNxU+1atULuEdGmkm0IvEgVZizP3f7G3kry6lgjh++L2cBjUWEHo2DP4" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <a href="#" name="btn-copy" id="btnToastCopyURL" title="copy link URL"
        data-copytext="http://dev.gotravelly.com/en/culinary/detail/25362432-my_lemon_yang_menyegarkan"
        data-show_title="My lemon yang menyegarkan">
        <span id="copy"><i class="far fa-copy"></i></span>
    </a>
    <div id="copy_to_clipboard-container" class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true"
        data-bs-autohide="true" data-bs-delay="5000">
        <div class="toast-body d-flex justify-content-between">
            <span><?php printf('hello world'); ?></span>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: When rendering your above snippet, my browser console is saying, _"Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css` with computed SHA-384 integrity 'SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk'. The resource has been blocked."_

Comment: Your link tag for Font Awesome is not valid (as @CBroe already mentioned). If I replace with a correct one the icon is visible. You can copy the link tag directly from cdnjs: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome/5.15.3

Comment: thank you. if one of you would post your answer below, I'd like to mark it as the correct answer